# didSet Not Observing Static Variables

Tags: ios, swift, static-variables, didset

I'm trying to use `didSet` on a static observed property but it's not running the if-else statement in the `didSet`. Here is the code:

```
    static var isCorrect: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if isCorrect {
            ViewController.theViewController.checkbox.image = UIImage(named: "tick")
        } else {
            ViewController.theViewController.checkbox.image = nil
        }
    }
}

static var theViewController = ViewController()
```

It is all in a class called `ViewController`. I'm changing the `isCorrect` variable in another view controller class and dismissing it after that but it doesn't seem to work.

The `checkbox` property used there is a variable of type `UIImageView`.

Am I doing anything wrong? If I am then what is the right way?

Comment: Are you using a storyboard for your view controller? If you are then you are using the wrong instance of your view controller in the didSet

Comment: Yes I am, indeed.

Comment: Why does the property need to be static? If it wasn’t you could probably do `self.checkbox.image = ...` in didSet

Comment: Because I'm changing this in another view controller class.

Comment: Don’t do that, pass the value between your view controllers instead

Comment: And also I am setting my storyboard view controller as the value of theViewController in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Okay. I'll try.

Comment: The didSet block is still not working.

Comment: Now it's working, it turns out that the answer variable was hard-coded.